# Склонение фамилии Петрович

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Фамилия Петрович склоняется, но только в мужском роде. Почему?

Comment: А как склонять фамилию Петрович в женском роде? Как она должна звучать, например, в дательном падеже?

Answer (score 3):

Грамота.ру [даёт подробное объяснение](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/) и приводит несколько простых правил склонения фамилий. В данном случае применимо следующее правило:

> 4. Если фамилия оканчивается на согласный (кроме фамилий на -ых, -их, о которых говорилось выше), то здесь – и только здесь! – имеет значение пол носителя фамилии. Все мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, склоняются – это закон русской грамматики. Все женские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, не склоняются.

Answer (score 2):

Различие при склонении (для данного класса фамилий) информативно: при отсутствии дополнительных оговорок оно помогает выявить, о ком в тексте идёт речь, о мужчине или о женщине.

Answer (score 1):

Фамилия **Петрович** склоняется по образцу существительных 2-го склонения, а это существительные мужского и среднего рода.

Классический пример ― Джон и Анна Смит. Склоняется только мужская фамилия: Джона Смита и Анны Смит.